# animating GIF, some GIF crash but some doesn't in Javascript, gifuct

Tags: javascript, gif, animated-gif

https://github.com/matt-way/gifuct-js

I'm making chrome extension that shows gif faster than original with gifuct-js. gifuct is gif parser and drawer for javascript...

[image: properly done]

[image]

As you can see when I use gifuct to draw gif, some gifs are crashed with white blurs...

Properly done gif is 6800kb and the crashed gif is 4464kb so the size of the gif is not the problem

I wonder why some gifs are crashed like this...

And how I cound fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by crashed? The white artifacts are likely occuring because the gifuct render demo doesn't do anything sophisticated with transparency.